# My html page won't show my stylesheet

Tags: html, css

My html page doesn't show the edits that should be made with my css page. I have tried to fix the problem for over an hour now and done everything I can think of. The page is linked with

```
link href="stlyes/css-ba.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
```

Which i believe is correct. I've checked and rechecked the name and any other things. It is saved in the folder styles as css-ba.css.

Comment: Should `href="stlyes` be `href="styles`?

Comment: Show us a minimum amount of code where we can see how you have it linked.

Comment: check that you have named the route after the one you wrote "stlyes" and not styles. So you have something like this? 
`<head>
 <link href="stlyes/css-ba.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>`
Press CTRL+U in your browser to see the source code of your page. Go to the link and open it in another tab, What do you get? 404? your css code?

Comment: Yes, Artur Capraro, that was it. Thank you so much. And I never knew the CTRL+U trick. I only started learning less than a week ago. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
link href="stlyes/css-ba.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
```

With:

```
link href="styles/css-ba.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
```

You have a spelling mistake "stlyes"

Answer (score 0):

- check spellings for "styles" in href="stlyes/css-ba.css"
- try deleting cache files and restart the browser